# Creating a sequence with a gap within a range

Tags: r, seq, rep

I am trying to create a sequence of numbers within a range, skipping every 4th number. I know it probably involves `seq` or `seq_len` somehow, but I can't seem to get it straight.

The sequence should be something like this:

```
c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11...48)
```

Comment: I don't think `48` should be in your sequence. One way: `(1:48)[as.logical((1:48) %% 4)]`.

Comment: You are right, the 48 should not appear in it. My bad. I need the range until 48, but actually skipping it. This is the full sequence I need: c(1,2,3, 5,6,7, 9,10,11, 13,14,15, ...until 47). Your way works-perfect!

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Please choose one of the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- 1:48
x[x%%4!=0]
# [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  9 10 11 13 14 15 17 18 19 21 22 23 25 26 27 29 30 31 33 34 35
# [28] 37 38 39 41 42 43 45 46 47
```

**UPDATE:**
I found an even faster approach.

```
x <- 1:48e6
mbm <- microbenchmark(
 steven = x[-seq.int(0L, length(x), 4L)],
 venyao1 = x[x %% 4 != 0],
 venyao2 = as.vector(matrix(x, nrow=4)[-4, ]),
 pascal = x[as.logical((x) %% 4)],
 times = 10
)

mbm
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# steven 1519.4170 1524.0044 1553.3609 1554.0616 1554.7951 1639.989    10
# venyao1 3323.2142 3327.3154 3382.2387 3369.9388 3426.3029 3502.881    10
# venyao2  919.8674  921.3917  932.3078  923.1563  923.6811 1007.784    10   
# pascal 3207.6932 3211.9832 3245.4686 3213.5090 3299.4639 3356.368    10
```

Comment: (+1) its strange... I cannot reproduce your results comparing against stevens method, I get them the same speed (ubuntu x32, R3.2.2). Yours is a bit faster however, if you change `as.vector` to `as.integer`

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe it was related to the enviroment. I was on Linux, X64, R3.1.1

Comment: Yen Yan, @StevenBeaupré;  yes, I think it must be related to the system, maybe even the PC  - surprised by the order of magnitude in the difference though, as completely contrasting results between the three of us. The upside is both your ,methods are fast.

Comment: From `microbenchmark` ... *Depending on the underlying operating system, different methods are used for timing* ....

Comment: Cheers Steven.  Obviously its not important in this case, but i do find the differences  interesting. Were all on *nix (me x32) , so i guess some of the difference is in our PC's (cpu speed, cache perhaps?), but i dont really have a scooby.  (....@VenYao ; apologies got your name wrong in previous comment ... really need to wear my spectacles these days)

Comment: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10). Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit). Under Linux node13 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64. It's okay @user20650

Comment: Haha. I was on Linux server. model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4620 0 @ 2.20GHz. cache size      : 16384 KB. And I have 64 cores.

Comment: 64 cores!!! is that enough?. Well, I think i think my system trumps you all (ahem, no not really) .... im on an eight year old laptop, dual core T9600 (2.8ghz, 6M cache) on ubuntu 14.04. Do these calculation only run on one core though? Does seem like certain speeds of processor favour different methods. I conclude that ill add it to the list of things i dont understand.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I tested on a windows PC. Your method is faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96895/discussion-between-ven-yao-and-user20650).

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
x <- 1:48
x[-seq.int(0L, length(x), 4L)]
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
x <- 1:48e6

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  steven    = x[-seq.int(0L, length(x), 4L)],
  venyao    = x[x %% 4 != 0],
  venyao2   = as.vector(matrix(x, nrow=4)[-4, ]),
  pascal    = x[as.logical((x) %% 4)],
  user20650 = as.integer(matrix(x, nrow=4)[-4, ]),
  times = 10
)
```

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
#    steven  326.2159  350.6567  354.2743  357.3672  359.9924  368.3123    10 a   
#    venyao 1388.9975 1395.8814 1417.3213 1400.1432 1455.2255 1470.7743    10    d
#   venyao2  613.9878  637.5377  639.1718  637.9342  640.1753  657.6627    10  b  
#    pascal 1236.6055 1243.8149 1265.1976 1249.1046 1304.5699 1316.8247    10   c 
# user20650  587.8511  596.5614  610.4037  602.3607  619.1915  670.8756    10  b
```

Comment: Even better. I am still learning R, and was trying to make a multi-boxplot figure that grouped certain variables, leaving a spacer. Thanks!